# Using C fopen in Windows 8 Runtime Component

Tags: windows-runtime, fopen, windows-8.1, storagefile, winrt-component

I am using a cross-platform library in a Windows Runtime Component (C++) in a Windows 8.1 Store (Metro) app. This library makes C style file calls such as `fopen`, `stat`, etc.

These operations work fine when the file is in the local app scope (e.g. in the app's local directory). But if the file is located in other locations (for instance on the "Desktop") then these operations fail. Is there a way to make `fopen` and other file calls outside the local app folder without having to switch to `StorageFile`? As an alternative I can only think of copying all files to the local app folder.

Regards,

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx

Comment: This does not really help because it relies on ``StorageFile``.

Comment: No, requested capabilities are *enforced* by the sandbox.  Regardless of what api you use.  The kind of help you are looking for doesn't exist.  If you want to tinker with the user's desktop then you must write a desktop app.  It is off limits to store apps.

Comment: Ok, I already suspected this.